# Enable/disable button when Input Element is Cleared

Tags: jquery, html, html-input

I have the following form:

```js
$('.search__input').keyup(function() {
          var empty = false;
            $('.search__input').each(function() {       
                if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                    empty = true;
                }
            });
        
            if (empty) {
                $('.search__button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $('.search__button').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
      });
    });
```

```html
<form class="search" action="my_url" autocomplete="on">
      <input type="search" class="search__input">
      <button type="submit" class="search__button">Search</button>
    </form>
```

I am using the following code to retrieve the autocomplete via a rest api:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".search__input").autocomplete({
    delay: 250,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var suggestURL = "my_url";
      suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: suggestURL,
        success: function (data) {
           response(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

However, there are other ways to make the input element empty other than keyup. For example, chrome has an x button that appears in the input element, which can be used to clear its content. What is the correct way to deal with such cases? I would be nice if there was an action that fired when the input becomes empty for any reason.

Comment: Use `.on('input',function(){})` instead of keyup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your form submits the search, if you add required to the input, you won't be able to hit submit when the search field is empty:

```
  <input type="search" class="search__input" required />
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in a named function. Then you can call it from the `keyup` handler, as well as other places that modify the inputs.

```js
function enable_disable()() {
  var empty = false;
  $('.search__input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
      empty = true;
    }
  });

  if (empty) {
    $('.search__button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('.search__button').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}

$('.search__input')
  .keyup(enable_disable)
  .autocomplete({
    delay: 250,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var suggestURL = "my_url";
      suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: suggestURL,
        success: function(data) {
          response(data);
        }
      });
    },
    close: enable_disable
  });
```

BTW, if you're using AJAX to get the suggestions, you can just use the URL as the value of the `source:` option, you don't have to write your own `$.ajax()` code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My rest URL is of the form "https://url.com/startswith?%QUERY" and then I use suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term) in my function. Can I still set the source with a url only and if so how?

Comment: You'll need to change how it gets the parameter. It sends it as `YOURURL?term=XXX` where `XXX` is the search term.

Comment: You could use a rewrite rule that rewrites `url.com/startswith?term=XXX` to `url.com/startswith?XXX`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of using `.keyup`, you could use `.onchange` which will fire anytime the contents of the input field is changed (however you may have to leave the input field for the change to be detected).